# How to access rails association attributes through Handlebar template

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, handlebars.js

When a request returns the json that is placed in the handlebar template how/can I access attributes of a rails association like the 'user' of a 'post' as the only attribute in the json is the user_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The associated model and attributes-optional, need to be passed to the json in the controller:

```
post.to_json(:include => :user => {:only => :username })
```

See [to_json (apidock)](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json)